# How to do idiomatic synchronization with time.After?

Tags: go, synchronization, timeout

I'm writing an application that queues incoming requests. If a request has been on the queue for more than a certain amount of time, I'd like to throw a timeout. I'm doing that with time.After:

```
timeoutCh := time.After(5 * time.Second)
select {
    case <-timeoutCh:
         //throw timeout 504
    case <-processing:
         //process request
}
```

The processing channel (along with the request) is put on the queue, and when a request is taken off to be processed, I send a signal to the channel to hit the case statement:

```
processing <- true
```

The problem with this is that if timeoutCh has already been selected, the processing channel will block, so I need some way to check whether the request has timed out.

I considered using a shared atomic boolean, but if I do something like this:

```
case <-timeoutCh:
     requestTimedOut = true
```

and then check the boolean before sending to the processing channel, there's still a race condition, because the timeoutCh case may have been selected, but the bool not yet set to true!

Is there an idiomatic way of dealing with this sort of synchronization problem in Go?

Comment: Is this the higher-level problem that you are trying to solve:  When removing requests from a queue, discard the request with an error if request was in the queue for longer than some specified duration.

Comment: Yes -- that is the problem I am trying to solve!

Comment: Does it work to use `struct { r Request, enqueueTime time.Time }` as the queue element type and check the enqueue time when removing an element from the queue?   `if time.Since(e.enqueueTime) > duration { /* discard with error */ }`

Comment: That almost works, except that the 504 wouldn't be returned as soon as the timeout was exceeded.

Comment: What about making processing a two way channel and sending a signal from your timeout block in the select? That way your queue can throw the request away by checking `<-processing`. Or have a separate channel specifically for that use like `hasTimedOut`. (Edit: I think I misunderstood your question ignore me)

Comment: Is the purpose of the queue to ensure that the processing code is not executed concurrently?  If yes, then there's a simpler approach.

Comment: The queue is helping with the implementation of a fairness algorithm, not helping make things more concurrent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a mutex coordinate processing of the data and timeout.

Define a type to hold the mutex, input, result, a channel to signal completion of the work and a flag indicating that the work, if any, is complete.

```
type work struct {
    sync.Mutex
    input    InputType
    result   ResultType
    signal   chan struct {}
    done     bool
}
```

The request handler creates and enqueues a work item and waits for a timeout or a signal from the queue processor. Either way, the request handler checks to see if the queue processor did the work and responds as appropriate.

```
func handler(resp http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w := &queueElement{
        input: computeInputFromRequest(req)
        signal:  make(chan struct{})
    }
    enqueue(w)

    // Wait for timeout or for queue processor to signal that the work is complete.
    select {
    case <-time.After(5 * time.Second):
    case <-w.signal:
    }

    w.Lock()
    done := w.done  // Record state of the work item.
    w.done = true   // Mark the work item as complete.
    w.Unlock()

    if !done {
        http.Error(w, "Timeout", http.StatusGatewayTimeout)
    }  else {
        respondWithResult(resp, w.result)
    }
}
```

The queue processor will look something like this:

```
 for {
   w := dequeue()
   w.Lock()
   if !w.done {
      w.done = true
      w.result = computeResultFromInput(w.input)
      close(w.signal)
   }
   w.Unlock()
}
```

To ensure that the request handler waits on the result, the queue processor holds the lock while processing the work item.

Comment: My understanding is that Go makes no guarantee about the order in which goroutines will be run. So, hypothetically, what if we check the context, and it's not cancelled. Then, time.After triggers, and we return a 504. Next, we send to resultCh. There's still a race condition, right? There's no way for the thing reading from the queue to be absolutely sure we haven't already served a 504. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: There's a race in that the queue may process the work after the request handler has returned.  There are no data races or races that will cause a goroutine to block forever.

Comment: Mhm, but the same is true of using a shared atomic boolean like I mentioned in the question, right? The main problem I'm trying to solve is making sure processing doesn't happen if we return a 504.

Comment: Looks great -- thanks for working on that -- really helpful!